# How can i run robot test cases without ride using test suite

Tags: robotframework

I am new to robot framework and wanted to see if i can run test cases without RIDE. I want to create test suite and run test cases sequentially without using RIDE. I went through documentation but could not understand it.

Ex: Test Suite

Test Case 1
Test Case 2
Test Case 3

i would like to put my references to all my resource files to test suite and run all test cases. I can do this using RIDE but wanted to know if i can do this without using it. Do i need to create batch file to do this or any other method to run?  Any example will help me. Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 3):

When you install robot, you also installed a program called `robot` (or `pybot` in older versions), which is the official robot test runner.

If you have a test suite named "my_tests.robot", you can open up a command prompt (bash on *nix, powershell or command.exe on windows) and type the following command (assuming that `robot` is in your PATH environment variable, which it probably is):

```
$ robot my_tests.robot
```

If you have a collection of suites in a folder, you can give pybot the name of the folder rather than the name of a test file.

To see a list of all robot command line options, use the --help option:

```
$ robot --help
```

For more information see [Starting test execution](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#starting-test-execution) in the robot framework users guide.

Comment: @JeevanChaitanya: `pybot` was the name of the test runner script prior to robot version 3. It is now called `robot`. They both perform the same function.

Comment: Thank you for the replay. Understood.

Answer (score 0):

if you use sublime-text/bracket/Atom/Emacs/vim ... you also have some plug-in :
http://robotframework.org/#tools

Answer (score 0):

1. Show the path of test suite

   exmp: Location of my 'catiav6' test script_
   cd C:\Users....\Desktop\catiav6
2. Run following command from cmd
   For single test case:
   pybot --test 'Name_of_single_test_case' 'Name_of_test_suite'
   For all test cases:
   pybot --test * 'Name_of_test_suite'